# Are there any good desktop linux tools for viewing a bazaar branch's history?

Tags: linux, version-control, dvcs, bazaar

For viewing diffs, I use the excellent [Meld](http://meld.sourceforge.net/) tool. But when it comes to looking at earlier revisions, I usually just find myself looking at the branch in Launchpad, where my code is hosted. Are there are good desktop tools for allowing me to do this? Ideally, [Olive](http://wiki.bazaar.canonical.com/Olive/)'s "History Mode" should do the trick, but it just gives me errors when I try to switch to History Mode.

I prefer Gtk tools, but I'm open to anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've not been that impressed with the Gtk tools, but the Qt tools for Bazaar are excellent.  Try [Bazaar Explorer](https://launchpad.net/bzr-explorer) with [QBzr](https://launchpad.net/qbzr): [they're very usable](http://doc.bazaar.canonical.com/explorer/en/visual-tour-gnome.html) and give a [good means of looking through the history](http://doc.bazaar.canonical.com/explorer/en/visual-tour-gnome.html#log-history).

To install the latest versions with Bazaar, do this:

```
cd ~/.bazaar/plugins
bzr branch lp:bzr-explorer explorer
bzr branch lp:qbzr
```

Answer (score 0):

bzr-gtk plugin has `visualize` command or just `vis`. Also QBzr has `qlog` command. The latter is a bit more powerful, but requires PyQt4/Qt4 libs.